# Which is the best 3-column 100% width pure CSS layout framework?

Tags: jquery, css, rich-internet-application

We're starting new project and we need **100% width** (100% height is a bonus :)), **3 column**, **pure CSS layout for business** RIA.

We checked out YAML, YUI, Blueprint and couple of others but seems that none offers or guarantees 100% compatibility with all major browsers.

Which one is the best for this purpose from your experience?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undoubtedly you've seen this already, but in his *A List Apart* website, Matthew Levine not only provides [the Holy Grail of 3-column layouts](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail), but explains how it works, in every detail.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading all ALA posts for some time. Alas this one was written when I was still young and green, thinking how tables and shiny buttons made in Photoshop are awesome :) Since I usually spend more time coding, I thought maybe all these fancy css frameworks are somehow important and should be used...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in most browsers IIRC. However, you will need some sort of javascript if you want a header/footer unless you use faux columns. For an RIA I think this is acceptable.

Personally, I never use CSS frameworks.

The example below should also work in IE6:

```
  <html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css" />
      <style type="text/css">
       html, body { height:100%; }

         .left { 
           width:200px;
           display:inline;
           float:left;
           background:blue;
           height:100%;
         }    

         .right { 
           width:200px;
           display:inline;
           float:right;
           background:red;
           height:100%;
         }

         .center {
           margin:0 200px;
           height:100%;
         }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="right">test</div>
      <div class="left">test</div>
      <div class="center">test</div>
   </body>
</html>
```